# Чем руководствоваться при выборе pixel per unit?

Tags: unity3d

подскажите как использовать опцию “pixel per unit” при импорте 2d спрайтов чтобы не было артефактов?

Answer (score 4):

Все зависит от того, какие артефакты вы имеете в виду. Если речь идет о графических артефактах, то Pixels Per Unit с ними никак не связан. Однако, что касается физики тут могут возникнуть некоторые нюансы.

Сам по себе Pixels Per Unit всего лишь отвечает за масштаб игрового мира, то есть сколько пикселей будет считаться как 1 unit на сцене. В графическом плане речь идет исключительно об удобстве. По умолчанию это значение равно 100, но иногда может быть удобно увеличить или уменьшить его.

Например, если вы используете тайловую карту у себя в проекте, где каждый тайл, к примеру, имеет разрешение 80*80, то для удобства работы с такими тайлам будет хорошим решением сделать их Pixels Per Unit равным 80. Таким образом вам будет легче расставлять объекты на сцене и манипулировать `transform` объектов из кода. При каких-то сложных работах с позициями объектов, координаты реже будут становиться дробными, в связи с чем точность вычислений будет выше (в плане округления float).

Также негласно принято считать, что  1 unit = 1 метру. Возможно, вам будет удобней измерять расстояние в каких-то других единицах, например 1 unit = 1 foot, или 1 unit = 1 inch и это тоже может служить причиной изменения этого значения.

Еще один момент, на который стоит обратить внимание - физика. Ее расчеты происходят относительно тех же unit'ов. По этому изменение значения Pixels Per Unit в игре, где у вас реализованы некоторые физические расчеты, может привести к нереалистичному физическому поведению. Иначе говоря, если вам придется прикладывать больше или меньше силы для перемещения объектов, в зависимости от того, как вы поменяли значение Pixels Per Unit. Это легко объясняется, если представить физический объект на сцене, на котором спрайт с разрешением 100*100- при Pixels Per Unit равным 100, он будет 1 unit * 1 unit (1 метр * 1 метр) в физическом размере. А если поменять Pixels Per Unit на 1, то тот же самый объект станет размером 100 unit * 100 unit (100 метров * 100 метров)